# Error en gráfico de barras en ggplot2: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (46)"

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

tengo un dataframe que luce de la siguiente forma:

```
|       |Sao Paulo |Bogota |Mexico |Santiago |Lima  |Rio de Janeiro|Caracas |Cali  |Recife|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1981   |1        |3       |3      |6        |1     |2             |3       |0     |1     |
|1982   |1        |4       |3      |5        |1     |1             |0       |0     |4     |
|1983   |3        |4       |5      |5        |4     |1             |7       |0     |2     |
|...    |...      |...     |...    |...      |...   |...           |...     |...   |...   |
|2020   |0        |2       |5      |5        |9     |1             |4       |1     |0     |
```

Necesito hacer un gráfico de barras, para el que yo pueda elegir un subconjunto de las ciudades en el eje horizontal del gráfico y una única fecha en el eje vertical, y este es el código que he estado intentando usar:

```
p <- ggplot(data=anual_change_t, aes(x=c("Lima","Bogota"), y="1982")) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")

p
```

Pero obtengo este error:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (46): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Pueden ayudarme?

Aquí les presento una parte de mis datos para que puedan reproducirlo:

```
 structure(list(`Sao Paulo` = c(-0.00752411164965841, 0.0412887465245744, 
    0.020920878349233, 0.0304899632424906, 0.0026190739934232), `Mexico City` = c(-0.00858235806970273, 
    0.0675304707144076, -0.00995206377715023, -0.0230856315886497, 
    -0.00432703286103911), Lima = c(-0.0193390181364576, 0.049352729240842, 
    0.0929229547913617, -0.113105853584711, -0.0171653896353017), 
        Bogota = c(-0.0254733683434182, -0.00515059960494002, 0.0228930063871382, 
        -0.061531343276225, 0.00708447667920834), `Rio de Janeiro` = c(-0.0135609910986883, 
        0.0118978209360105, 0.00842649575171037, 0.0243821742105042, 
        -0.0198762101230759)), row.names = c("1981", "1982", "1983", 
    "1984", "1985"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `aes()` espera las variables de tu `data.frame` y no un vector de `character` como le estarías pasando, lo mismo pasa con `y`, le estás pasando una cadena con el año y no la variable.

Pero hay un problema de fondo, tus datos no resultan del todo "amigables" para `ggplot`, resolverlo de la forma en que los tienes estructurados se puede, pero es mucho más trabajo, por lo que te sugiero, transformar los datos de un formato ancho a uno largo:

```
anual_change_t %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Año") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Año, names_to="Ciudad") -> plot_data

plot_data
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   Año   Ciudad            value
   <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 1981  Sao Paulo      -0.00752
 2 1981  Mexico City    -0.00858
 3 1981  Lima           -0.0193 
 4 1981  Bogota         -0.0255 
 5 1981  Rio de Janeiro -0.0136 
 6 1982  Sao Paulo       0.0413 
 7 1982  Mexico City     0.0675 
 8 1982  Lima            0.0494 
 9 1982  Bogota         -0.00515
10 1982  Rio de Janeiro  0.0119 
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Hemos transformado los datos en una estructural "larga" y convertido el nombre de fila en una columna. Ahora sí podemos hacer lo que buscas, usamos el verbo `filter()` para seleccionar ciudades y años:

```
plot_data %>% 
  filter(Ciudad %in% c("Lima","Bogota"),
         Año == 1982) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Ciudad, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.... Con tu ayuda se solucionó gran parte de mi problema... Solo tengo una pregunta... Cambia en algo código si en lugar de un vector con solo dos ciudades ingreso un vector con más ciudades... Es que hice el intento con un vector de tres ciudades y solo me mostró los dos últimos elementos de ese vector...

Comment: No, no cambia en nada que sea 1, 2 o N valores, revisa la ortografía del valor, acentos y esas cosas, por que debería funcionar igual.

Comment: Tienes razón... Sí funcionó. Ahora solo falta hacer ediciones de forma a la gráfica. Mil gracias!